# Memory usage unknown, how to find which process uses it and free it?

Tags: android, android-memory

I did the same [question here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62928/memory-usage-unknown-how-to-find-which-process-uses-it-and-free-it):: but since there is no reply, I try it here.

Is there a way to find via code or command line to find what is using that much memory in the phone? which its show as unknown! :S since it makes it slow and lag a lot when connected to the computer. or just changing from one application to another.

[image]